# How to publish my android application for media boxes like Minix or Nuvola in Google Play Store

Tags: google-play, android-mediaplayer, android-4.4-kitkat

I published my Android application with the below properties of AndroiodManifest.xml.

But I can't see my Android application in Google Play store of Minix or Nuvola 4k media box.

I would appreciate if anyone let me know how I fix it.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>

<compatible-screens>
    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480"/> <!-- xxhdpi -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640"/> <!-- xxxhdpi -->

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480"/> <!-- xxhdpi -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640"/> <!-- xxxhdpi -->

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480"/> <!-- xxhdpi -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="640"/> <!-- xxxhdpi -->

</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"   android:required="false" />
```